# Avoid duplicated function call in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have build a function **getuser()** in which I recieve json data from php into javascript. I call this function when document gets ready. My problem is that I am also using jquery post for live updation of that record and for that reason I have to call that function **getuser()** again due to this it shows duplicate result. First when document gets ready socend on jquery post function.

**HTML**

```
   <!--It has onclick event-->

  <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary modify" onclick="update_user()">UPDATE</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
//This is function which gets json array from php
function getuser() {
    $.get("getuser.php", function (data) {
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
            var student = data[i];
            var slash = " / ";
            $("#output").append("<tr><td>" + student.name + "</td><td>" + student.gender + "</td><td>" + student.age + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + student.city + "</td><td><a href='#' style='text-decoration: none'  class='update' id='" + student.id + "' onclick='reply_click(this.id)'>Update</a>" + slash + "<a style='text-decoration: none' href='#'>Delete</a></td></tr>");
        }
    });
}

//when document gets ready it will show the record
if($(document).ready()) {
    //   getuser();
    getuser();
}


//This is jquery post. When I click button (in html section) it will get form values and sent to php page
    //in return it will call getuser() function again which results of duplicate display of record

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.modify').click(function() {
        var gender = '';
        if($('.male').is(':checked')){


            gender='Male';

        }else{


            gender='Female';
        }
        $.post("update.php",
            {name: $('.name').val(),gender:gender,city:$('.city').val(),age:$('.age').val(),id:$('.id').val()},
            function (data) {
                //here is the function  call again
                getuser();

            }
        );
    });
});
```

Kindy tell me that is there any way I avoid second call in post function and the record gets update without function call again.I need to avoid duplicate result. Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't blindly append when you update, "overwrite or update" depending on whether the thing you're showing is already on the page or not, respectively.

Comment: `if($(document).ready()) {` what..

Comment: append is already in done when window gets ready.

Comment: @KevinB when window gets ready (completely loaded)

Comment: @ZainFarooq that doesn't do what you think it does...

Comment: ok.. take it same as ` $(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: but... it isn't even remotely the same. `getuser` will be called immediately, regardless of whether or not the document is ready.

Comment: Sure.. But I thinks problem is in post function

Comment: What you are describing is only possible if the user is clicking the button twice.

Comment: @Kevin B  Oh boy. I suspect that's actually _calling_ the ready function..

Comment: uhm... it shouldn't be... there's no function signature for that usage. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @KevinB when user click the button it will call jquery post function in there there is a getuser() call again

Comment: @ZainFarooq well, yeah, you're telling it to. stop telling it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of you thanks for your suggestions. I have found the solution here by just adding `$("#tbody").html('');` in `getuser()` before loop. 
Here is the code which works fine for me

```
 function getuser() {
    $.get("getuser.php", function (data) {
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        $("#tbody").html('');//newly added

        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
            var student = data[i];
            var slash = " / ";
                           $("#output").append("<tr><td>" + student.name + "</td><td>" + student.gender + "</td><td>" + student.age + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + student.city + "</td><td><a href='#' style='text-decoration: none'  class='update' id='" + student.id + "' onclick='reply_click(this.id)'>Update</a>" + slash + "<a style='text-decoration: none' href='#'>Delete</a></td></tr>");
        }
    });
}
```

All of you thanks again!

Comment: Please don't post an answer to your own question. Just update your question.

Comment: but then the question would be useless

Comment: No it wouldn't, you edit the question and, at the bottom, you add an UPDATE section with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to read the docs on [jquery document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), and learn the difference between a function reference and actually calling a function.  document.ready expects you to pass in a function definition to be called *when the page is ready*. It doesn't actively tell you if the page is ready, the first way you're calling it. The second way you're calling it is actually correct.

Second, replace `$("#output").append` with `$("#output").html`, which will update/replace the contents of that element every time, instead of just adding more and more.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` test will always return true because `document.ready` returns the JQuery object. So, you are always causing the call to `getuser()` to happen.

You can see the return value from `document.ready()` here:

```js
console.log($(document).ready());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is an incorrect usage of `document.ready()`. You don't need to write a test for `document.ready`, just write a callback function for that event and let the browser do it correctly for you.

**[Read the docs on document.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)**

**Solution**:

This:

```
//when document gets ready it will show the record
if($(document).ready()) {
    //   getuser();
    getuser();
}
```

Should be this:

```
//when document gets ready it will show the record
$( document ).ready(getuser);
```

Or even:

```
$(getuser);
```

As for you getting the results a second time, just overwrite the old results instead of appending them.

This:   `$("#output").append(...`

Should be:  `$("#output").html(...`

Comment: @ZainFarooq My understanding of the question is that `getuser` should only get one record.

Comment: I didn't mentioned there. Thats why I was appending

Comment: When the page loads, `getuser` is called. When the button is pressed, an update happens and `getuser` is called again (so that the updated information can be gotten). By replacing `.append` with `.html`, you throw the old user data away and replace it with the new user data. What's the problem?

Comment: I am iterating data in loop in getuser(). .html overwrites the every previous `tr` with new`tr`. Thats why I was appending every new `tr` down the previous `tr`

Comment: Can you explain "exactly" what a second call to `getuser` should do?

Comment: It should overwrite previous record with new updated

Comment: I have added `$("#tbody").html('');` just before the second call to getuser but the table blinks

Comment: I think `$("#tbody").html('');` is the only solution?

Comment: @ZainFarooq When you say "previous record", do you mean the last row of the table?

Comment: Hi sir, I have got the solution.